# Find algorithm in 2-3 BST tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is there an algorithm that with a given [2-3 tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree) T and a pointer to some node v in said tree, the algo can change the key of the node v so T would remain a legal 2-3 tree, in O(logn/loglogn) amortized efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Assume it was possible, with the algorithm f, we will show we can sort an array with `O(n*logn/loglogn)` time complexity.

```
sort array A of length n:
(1) Create an  2-3 tree of size n, with no importance to keys. let it be T.
(2) store all pointers to nodes in T in a second array B.
(3) for each i from 0 to n:
   (3.1) f(B[i],A[i]) //modify the tree: pointer: B[i] new value: A[i]
(4) extract elements from T back to A inorder.
```

**correctness:**

After each activation of `f` the  tree is legal. After finishing activating `f` on all elements of `T` and all elements of `A`, the tree is legal and contains all elements. Thus, extracting elements from A, we get back the sorted array.

**complexity:**

(1)Creating a tree [no importance which keys we put] is `O(n)` we can put `0` in all elements, it doesn't matter

(2)iterating `T` and creating `B` is `O(n)`

(3)activating `f` is `O(logn/loglogn)`, thus invoking it `n` times is `O(n*logn/loglogn)`

(4) extracting elements is just a traversal: `O(n)`

Thus: total complexity is `O(n*logn/loglogn)`

But sorting is an `Omega(nlogn)` problem with comparisons based algorithms. contradiction.

**Conclusion**: desired `f` doesn't exist.

Comment: An even stronger result is that you can't do updates any faster than Omega(log n), since for the same reason you would be able to break the Omega(n log n) sorting barrier.